# Update SQL database Failed when deploying

Tags: asp.net, azure, asp.net-core, azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service

I have a Web Application(ASP.NET Core project) with two migrations and I published it to Azure. At the end I got a message that Web App was published successfully but I see these warnings in output console:

```
Info: Adding database (data source=tcp:xxxdbserver.database.windows.net,1433;initial catalog=xxx_db;user id=yyy@xxxdbserver)
Warning: Cannot connect to the database 'xxx_db'.  
Retrying operation 'Add' on object dbFullSql (data source=tcp:xxxdbserver.database.windows.net,1433;initial catalog=xxx_db;user id=yyy@xxxdbserver). Attempt 1 of 20.
Warning: The database 'xxx_db' could not be created.  
Retrying operation 'Add' on object dbFullSql (data source=tcp:xxxdbserver.database.windows.net,1433;initial catalog=xxx_db;user id=yyy@xxxdbserver). Attempt 2 of 20.
Info: Using ID 'zzz' for connections to the remote server.
Info: Adding file (xxx\appsettings.json).
Info: Adding file (xxx\appsettings.Production.json).
```

And when I am looking in Database Activity Log on Azure Portal I see one failed operation with the following summary:

```
Operation name
Update SQL database
Time stamp
Sat Oct 22 2016 20:56:26 GMT+0300 (GTB Daylight Time)
Error code
40619
Message
The edition 'Free' does not support the database max size '1073741824'.
```

I never set a database max size. The strange thing is that everything is working fine in the app online. Was that a failed operation and it eventually succeeded? Where is this coming from?

Comment: I have the same error when I deployed Database based on Free service plan. But if I choose Shared, it works.